# Jenkinsfile declare variables if else conditon

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to set up multiple variables depending on the BRANCH name, however I've issues to declare them since the pipeline fail every time due syntax errors - or maybe there is a better way to archive my goal

basically the idea is that depending on the branch name the variables are set to have an unique jenkins file across the branches

example jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  def aws_environment = "${BRANCH_NAME}"
  if (aws_environment == 'test') {
    API_Cluster = 'cluster"
    API_Task = 'task'
    ecr_repo = 'XXX.dkr.'
    API_Service = 'apiservice'
    API_DockerFile = "dockerfiletest"
  } else if (aws_environment == "master") {
    API_Cluster = 'cluster'
    API_Task = 'task'
    ecr_repo = 'XXX.dkr'
    API_Service = 'apiservice'
    API_DockerFile = 'dockerfile'
  } else {
    throw "no environment selected!"
  }
  agent any
  stages {

    stage('Build Details') {
      steps {
        echo 'The build ENV is ${BRANCH_NAME}'
        echo 'Services: ${API_Service}'
        echo 'Cluster:  ${API_Cluster}'
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Are you putting all of your logic inside a Jenkinsfile or are you using a shared library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this sort of manipulation before inside string interpolation, but it's kind of a pain if you have multiple alternations (my use case was `ECR_REPO = "${env == 'prod' ? prod_ecr : dev_ecr}"`. I'd prefer a "setup" stage.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Setup') {
      steps {
        script {
          switch(env.BRANCH_NAME) {
            case 'test':
              API_Cluster = 'cluster"
              API_Task = 'task'
              ecr_repo = 'XXX.dkr.'
              API_Service = 'apiservice'
              API_DockerFile = "dockerfiletest"
            case 'master':
              API_Cluster = 'cluster'
              API_Task = 'task'
              ecr_repo = 'XXX.dkr'
              API_Service = 'apiservice'
              API_DockerFile = 'dockerfile'
          }
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Build Details') {
      steps {
        // do whatever
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also since this data seems to be separated by branch, consider writing this data in VCS and parsing it with `readFile` (or `readJSON` or etc) to find the right data.